# How to update character_set_client to utf8mb4 in mysql 5.5.x

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Following commands gives the charset info

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE  'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE  'collation%'`

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVntt.jpg)

Any idea how to change **character_set_client** to **utf8mb4** ??

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ?

```
SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4';
```